# Javascript re-load of page before sending data to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

**Background:**
 I want to create a login form, the user input the "user ID" and "password".
 My *JavaScript* file checks certain parameters. If the data does not comply
 with them the my page is re-load.
 If the data is approved then after checking in JavaScript my *PHP* script
 kicks in and does other stuff.

**Question:** the problem I am having is that even though the data is not complaint with the JavaScript check up my page is not re-loading. It keeps sending the data to my PHP script.

Which is want I do not want.

I want to re-loed the same page and not send to PHP. I want to send the data to PHP when the data has passed the JavaScript check up.

**CODE:**

**HTML SECTION**

[image]

**JavaScript SECTION**

[image]

**Thank you**

If you guys can suggest a way to approach this situation it would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Put the relevant code in your question, not in screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect , you don't need to reload the page in case of none valid entries , I would suggest doing something similar to the following :

```js
function checkForm(){
  if(document.getElementById("whatever").value != 'xyz') {
    console.log("False !")
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

```html
<form action="something.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
<input type="text" id="whatever">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @ Ashraf, you suggestion worked form my problem. Thank you.

Comment: One last question, can you explain to me how does the return value in "  onsubmit="return checkf()"    " work. I'm new to JavaScript so this piece of code is somewhat confusing. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Andy , To trap the submission of the form, for example to validate the form fields, you can use the `onSubmit` event handler . If the form validation is supposed to stop the form from being submitted then it has to return false from the event handler: `onSubmit="return false"` , otherwise : `onSubmit="return true"` . This is actually what the function `checkForm` does .

Comment: @ Ashraf, got it. Thank you.

Comment: Great . Please feel free to accept the answer . @Andy